# Set webpack with lite-server on angularJS app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, webpack

I'm new to webpack, I'm trying to setup webpack with lite-server hot reloading on angularJS app.

I'll explain step by step what I did so far and you'll probably troubleshoot.

So I created my package.json which is:

```
{
  "name": "app",
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "description": "front",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "lite-server"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "^1.6.9",
    "angular-route": "^1.6.9",
    "webpack": "^4.4.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.4",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "lite-server": "^2.3.0"
  }
}
```

then in root folder I added webpack.config.js

```
//webpack.config.js
module.exports = {
    entry: './src/app.js',
    output: {
        path: './src/bin',
        filename: 'app.bundle.js',
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
            },
            { test: /\.html$/, loader: "html" },
            { test: /\.css$/, loader: "style!css" }
        ]
    },
    devtool: "#inline-source-map"
}
```

then I added .babelrc file inside root folder

```
{ "presets": [ "es2015" ] }
```

and last 2 steps I created src folder in root with 2 files inside - app.js and index.html

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    import angular from 'angular';

    angular
        .module('app')
        .config(configure);

    configure.$inject = []; // some providers 'll be injected in here

    function configure() {
        console.log('config run');
    }

})();
```

---

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body data-ng-app="app">
        <!-- files 'll be built in here -->
        <script src="bin/app.bundle.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

And that's all about code my files structure look like this:

[image: img]

*bin* folder is empty. I run `npm start` script and it's actually starting this lite-server thing but it throwing error 404

> 18.04.01 14:31:23 404 GET /index.html

---

I want my webpack to compile all files needed at the moment and create this bundle then load it in index.html. What I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

In your package.json file, under the "start" script, you only start the lite-server with default settings. So I believe you are not starting webpack at all, and thus the artifacts never gets built to the bin folder.

Just a warning though, you cannot do:

```
"start": "lite-server && webpack"
```

because webpack still wont run. Why? because webpack will only run after lite-server is finished executing, which in this case, will never finish. Perhaps give https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-run-all a try to run both concurrently.

Comment: I added this but it still show error 404 of inxdex.html

Comment: Are there files inside src/bin folder? Also, since you are using webpack vsn 4, you may need to use https://github.com/webpack/webpack-cli instead

Comment: No there is no files inside bin folder. You mean use webpack-cli instead of...?

Comment: Could you please explain some more, step by step what should I do to make it run? I can't figure it out.

Comment: Right now, lite-server is expecting files to be located in /src/bin/ so you need webpack to build files and output to that location. Try to run webpack in the terminal by itself first and get it to output files there.